# C++ breaking a loop with keypress

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, keypress

I am writing a console application for windows where there is a while loop that goes through over and over, and I am trying to find a way to be able to break out of the loop with any keypress, while the loop keeps running. cin or getch stop the program to wait for input but I don't want that. Any help?

Comment: You'll have to poll the keyboard inside the loop to see if a key has been pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop must have a stop condition, like `while(count < x)`

When the user presses a key, set a Boolean to false and make your while loop check for that

`while(!keyPressed){}`